# Unresolved external symbol when use boost TLS

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I have problem with error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol.

I have a class CThread split to CThread.h and CThread.cpp

In CThread.h i have included boost/thread/tss.hpp, i have also 2 class:

CThreadLocalStorageSlot and 
CThread : public CThreadLocalStorageSlot (derived).

in class CThreadLocalStorageSlot i have:

static boost::thread_specific_ptr ThreadLocalStorage_;

but in linking time i have:

1>CThread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::thread_specific_ptr CThreadLocalStorageSlot::ThreadLocalStorage_" (?ThreadLocalStorage_@CThreadLocalStorageSlot@threads@2V?$thread_specific_ptr@VCThread@threads@@boost@@A)

Why ? i have included boost file which is responsible for TLS so i have definition of thread_specific_pt.

Any sugestion ?

Best regards

Comment: You are linking the with the correct boost_thread library I suppose? And you also have a definition for your static class member variable?

Comment: Yep, i have #include <boost/thread/tss.hpp> in my header.
And CThread.h looks like:


#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

class __declspec(dllexport) CThreadLocalStorageSlot
{
public:

 static boost::thread_specific_ptr<CThread> ThreadLocalStorage_;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) CThread : public CThreadLocalStorageSlot
{
//class implementation
}

Comment: That doesn't answer my question about you've been linking with the library. Anyway your fault is the missing definition for `CThreadLocalStorageSlot::ThreadLocalStorage_`.

Comment: Could you give me some example of definition which i have to write, because i have pointer to tls<type which is CThread> and i could use this ptr somewhere else in code, for example ThreadLocalStorage_.reset(new CThread).

Comment: The syntax is explained in the dupe.